# pgfplots addplot+: Position pins on same line

Tags: pgfplots

Given the following plot with manually inserted pins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} []
                \addplot+[smooth,mark=]{x^2}
                node[pos=0.3,pin={[black]above:$0.3$}]{}
                node[pos=0.6,pin={[black]above:$0.6$}]{};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to position the pin labels s.t. they are on the same line, specifically same absolute y coordinate for all labels. I have only been able to shift relatively (shift=...).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please complete your code snippet and make it compilable ...

Comment: Please have a look to question https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that it shows you how to build an compilable code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I don't know if there is a simple way to redefine pins to do what you want, but it is straightforward to achieve it by other means.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} []
                \addplot+[smooth,mark=]{x^2}
                coordinate[pos=0.3] (p1) 
                coordinate[pos=0.6] (p2);
        \end{axis}
        \draw[ultra thin,shorten <=2pt] (p1) -- ++ (0.1,0.5) node[above] (l1) {$0.3$};
        \draw[ultra thin,shorten <=2pt] (p2) --  ([xshift=-0.1]p2 |- l1.south)
        node[above] (l2) {$0.6$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That will do the trick, thank you very much.